# Getting elements out of a NamingEnumeration

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, java1.4

I'm trying to get the elements out of a namingenumeration.
The namingenumeration itself is not null, but hasNext() gives me false.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
            DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(
                    Environment.getEnvironment());



            SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
            controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
             String[] attrIDs = { "cn", "givenname", "sn", "mail" };
             controls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
            NamingEnumeration enumResult = context.search(
                    "DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE", "(CN=*)",
                    controls);
            System.out.println(enumResult.hasMore());

            context.close();

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid credentials");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Lookup failed: " + e);
        }
}
```

Structure of AD (on Localhost using AD-LDS)

> DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE
>   ->OU=Accounts
>      ==>CN=John Doe
>      ==>CN=Jane Doe
>   ->CN=LostAndFound
>   ->CN=NTDS Quotas
>   ->CN=Roles
>   ->OU=System Accounts
>      ==>CN=PortalAdmin

[image: Structure of Directory]

Narrowing my searchbase to "OU=ACCOUNTS,DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE" gives the following error

> Lookup failed: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code
>   32 - 000020 8D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data
>   0, best match of: 'DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE' ]; remaining name 'OU=ACCOUNTS,DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE'

---

solution:

```
try {

            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(Environment.getEnvironment());



            // Get all the attributes of named object
            Attributes attrs = ctx
                    .getAttributes("cn=John Doe,ou=Accounts,DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE");

            if (attrs == null) {
                System.out.println("No attributes");
            } else {
                /* Print each attribute */
                try {
                    for (NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll(); ae.hasMore();) {
                        Attribute attr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                        System.out.println("attribute: " + attr.getID());

                        /* print each value */
                        for (NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll(); e.hasMore(); System.out
                                .println("value: " + e.next()))
                            ;
                    }
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



            ctx.close();

        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid credentials");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Lookup failed: " + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with doing some basic sanity checks. For instance, that the data returned by `Environment.getEnvironment()` is correct (url, port, user, password) and allows a connection to the directory server. Also check that there are no network problems and that you can, in fact, access the server.

Try limiting the search base a bit more, for instance: "OU=Accounts,DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE" and see if some results are returned. Also check if the objects in the expected results actually have the attributes "cn", "givenname", "sn", "mail".

Other than that, there are no obvious mistakes in the code shown in the question, it *should* work fine.

Comment: AD is running local using AD-LDS (new version of ADAM). If I try adding OU=ACCOUNTS to my searchbase, it gives an error: `Lookup failed: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 000020 8D: NameErr: DSID-031522C9, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of: 'DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE' –`

Comment: That's strange, assuming the tree structure in the question is correct, it should be a valid search base. If possible, update the question with a screenshot showing the actual tree structure in the directory

Comment: And how about `OU=Accounts,DC=PORTAL,DC=COMPANY,DC=BE` ? I'm not _that_ familiar with AD, it might be case-sensitive

Comment: Nope, same error. Microsoft stuff **usually** isn't case sensitive

Comment: It's possible that the user used for connecting doesn't have enough privileges for performing a search below the base of the directory

Comment: Adding my user to the admin group fixed the error. `enumResult.hasMore()` is still false, though

Comment: Another sanity check - try connecting with the admin user (not your user) and perform the search again, to rule out other permission-related problems

Comment: I was connected with the admin, just forgot to add him to the admin group.

Comment: Got the code working by myself, but because of the helpfull advice (especially with the admin), i'll give you the correct answer